# MySQL Load Data Infile Null and Expression

Tags: mysql, csv, import, null, formula

I would like to take data from a simple csv file and put it into a MySQL table (which I have already prepared). Some of the columns have values of 'NULL' strings, and I can successfully convert those to null values on import. However, I would also like the values that are not null to be put through a conversion formula, which I can also do successfully. My problem is that I cannot seem to do both at once. That is, I want to take values from a column in my csv file, put them through a formula before import, and yet take out the 'NULL' strings and replace them with null values in MySQL. So far my code is this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/Spencer/Desktop/WebProjects/WeatherMan/csvdata/day2/alabama_day2.csv'
INTO TABLE alabama_d
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(primary_id, station_id, @date, @precipitation, @snowfall, @maxtemp, @mintemp)
SET date = str_to_date(@date, '%m/%d/%y'),
precipitation = nullif(@precipitation, 'NULL'),
precipitation = @precipitation/100 * 2.54,
snowfall = nullif(@snowfall, 'NULL'),
snowfall = @snowfall/100 * 2.54,
maxtemp = nullif(@maxtemp, 'NULL'),
maxtemp = @maxtemp/10 * 9/5 + 32,
mintemp = nullif(@mintemp, 'NULL'),
mintemp = @mintemp/10 * 9/5 + 32;
```

If I put the nullif's first, the null values are correctly imported, but the data does not go through the formulas. If I put the formulas first, they work, but then the null values are not imported. I am stuck as to how I can get both at once. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was not making use of the one-line IF statement. Now my code works. It is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Spencer/Desktop/WebProjects/WeatherMan/csvdata/day2/alabama_day2.csv'
INTO TABLE alabama_d
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(primary_id, station_id, @date, @precipitation, @snowfall, @maxtemp, @mintemp)
SET date = str_to_date(@date, '%m/%d/%y'),
precipitation = if(@precipitation = 'NULL', null, @precipitation/100 * 2.54),
snowfall = if(@snowfall = 'NULL', null, @snowfall/10 * 2.54),
maxtemp = if(@maxtemp = 'NULL', null, @maxtemp/10 * 9/5 + 32),
mintemp = if(@mintemp = 'NULL', null, @mintemp/10 * 9/5 + 32);
```